# How do I reference a sheet in google sheets by using name of the sheet name from a cell within the main sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here is the scenario:

I am creating a budget and my sheet names are July 2022, August 2022, etc...

I have a "Totals" sheet that will gather and aggregate information from every sheet that I created for every month.  Within this "Totals" sheet the column name for each month will match the name of the sheet created for that month i.e., if in Totals sheet the column header is January 2023 so will the sheet name that corresponds with the incoming data for that month.

What I would like to do is call that sheet based on the column header...

For example...

If E1 in the "Total" sheet is "August 2022" and the cell in the actual Sheet for "August 2022" is D13 then I would like to use E1 reference to call the sheet and that cell.
='E1'!D13

The obvious error I get when I do this is that E1 does not exist #REF! - Unresolved Sheet name 'E1'.

Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `INDIRECT()` function. Try-

```
=INDIRECT("'" & E1 & "'!D13")
```

- ***Reference***

[INDIRECT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en)